# Python : ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 305768

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a large file thru python but getting below error -

```
input_file = pd.read_csv("Input_File.csv")
```

But getting this error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 305768
```

I searched thru the solution stackoverflow and tried few. Below one worked but it skip line -

```
input_file = pd.read_csv("Input_File.csv", engine='python', encoding='utf-8',error_bad_lines=False)
```

It gives this msg but process the file -

```
Skipping line 305769: unexpected end of data
```

How can I process the file without skipping the line. Any other suggestion I can try?

Comment: is there something weird at that line?

Comment: I could not find anything weird at that line. Look like any other line. Not sure if it is pointing to right line

Comment: is it possible that the line ending is something other than `\n` or `\r\n` ?

Comment: Is there way to find out this if the line ending with \n or \r\n?

Comment: Reading the file in python, without parsing. And printing the line. Or converting the line to hexadecimal and posting it here. I'd inspect the surrounding lines too, as it may not be an issue with the specific line

Comment: Ok found the issue. File is having multiline rows. Infact lots of them. I break the file thru nifi into multiple files because of which some of the files end up breaking in the middle of multiline rows. Now I need to figure out how to split the file without splitting them from middle of the multiline rows.

Answer (score 1):

Just passing `csv.QUOTE_NONE` to quoting param for `read_csv` method.

```py
import csv
input_file = pd.read_csv('Input_File.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: I meet same issue and this one works.

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to only delete that specified row and see it works